# ChartJS Pie Chart How default just show 2 legend datas

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to show 10 data in a pie chart, but only show 2 of them.

my version is `v2.8.0`

```
chart.getDatasetMeta(i).hidden=true;
```

this is work in bar charts, but not work in pie.

```
var donutOptions = {...}


var donutChartCanvas = $(pieChart).get(0).getContext(2d);
var donutData = {
                 labels: [],
                 texts: [],
                 datasets: [
                    {
                        data: [ ],
                        backgroundColor : []
                    }
                 ]
                };

var donutChart = new Chart(donutChartCanvas, {
                plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
                type: doughnut,
                data: donutData,
                options: donutOptions
            });
```

getDatasetMeta undefined.

now is:

[image: this]

I want to this:

[image: that]

Comment: Why dont you sum the groups of data that you want before you send them in to the chart?

Answer (score 0):

I find a work way, try it.

add

```
legend : {

                }
```

into option

```
var donutOptions     = {
                maintainAspectRatio : false,
                responsive : true,
                animation: {
                    animateScale: true,
                    animateRotate: true
                },
                tooltips: {
                    intersect: false,
                    callbacks: {
                        label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                            ...
                        }
                    },
                },
                plugins: {
                    datalabels: {
                        ...
                        },
                    },
                },
                legend : {

                }

            };
```

and use this

```
donutChart.chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[index].hidden = true;

donutChart.update();
```

[image]